# An image that has been replaced re-appears again if I click the upload window again

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I have this issue that I can't seem to find a solution for. I have an 'upload image' area that's part of my form. You're allowed to either upload an image that has been downloaded on your computer or copy and paste an image address in the url, which should render the image in the image window. Everything works fine, except if:

1. I upload a downloaded image from my computer [downloaded-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU0f2.png)
2. I decide to instead copy an image url from the internet and use that instead [image-from-internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmy1O.png)
3. The image from the internet appears and overwrites the old image
4. I click on the image window again
5. The old image reappears and overwrites my new image [old-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW3fY.png)

I've tried resetting the form control of the image window when the user clicks on it, but that ends up clearing the entire image window, discarding the image. How do I prevent the old image from overwriting my new image?

The code snippets:

```js
isLoadingImage = false;
imageUrl ? : string;
imageContainerSelected = true;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.initFormFields();
}

beforeUpload = (file: NzUploadFile, _fileList: NzUploadFile[]) =>
  new Observable((observer: Observer < boolean > ) => {
    let isLt2M;
    if (file.size) {
      isLt2M = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < 0.2;
    }
    if (!isLt2M) {
      this.message.error('Image must be smaller than 200KB!');
      observer.complete();
      return;
    }
    observer.next(isLt2M);
    observer.complete();
  });

uploadCompanyImage = (item: NzUploadXHRArgs) => {
  const fileToUpload = item.file as any;
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(fileToUpload);
  reader.onload = () => {
    this.formValues.patchValue({
      company: {
        imageUrl: reader.result ? .toString()
      }
    });
    this.imageUrl = reader.result ? .toString();
  };
};

checkForExistingImage(): boolean {
  while (this.formValues.get('company.imageUrl') ? .value === '' || this.formValues.get('company.imageUrl') ? .value === null) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

selectImageInputBar(): void {
  this.imageContainerSelected = false;
}

selectImageContainer(): void {
  this.imageContainerSelected = true;
  if (this.formValues.get('company.imageUrl') ? .value === '' || this.formValues.get('company.imageUrl') ? .value === null) {
    this.formValues.get('company.imageUrl') ? .reset();
  }
}

getImageUrlFromInputBar(): string {
  const selectedImageUrl = this.formValues.get('company.imageUrl') ? .value.trim();
  return selectedImageUrl;
}

getImageUrlFromImageContainer(): string {
  const selectedImageUrl = this.imageUrl || '';
  return selectedImageUrl.trim();
}




initFormFields() {
  this.formValues = this.fb.group({
    id: 0,
    userId: '',
    jobTitle: ['', [Validators.required]],
    description: '',
    company: this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      url: '',
      industry: '',
      imageUrl: ''
    }),
    companyLocation: this.fb.group({
      city: '',
      state: '',
      postCode: '',
      country: ''
    }),
    dateStart: ['', [Validators.required]],
    dateEnd: '',
    associatedGoals: [],
  });
}
```

```html
<nz-form-item class="container">
  <nz-form-control class="upload-col">
    <div>
      <nz-upload class="avatar-uploader company-image-container" nzName="avatar" nzListType="picture-card" [nzShowUploadList]="false" [nzBeforeUpload]="beforeUpload" [nzCustomRequest]="uploadCompanyImage" tabindex="-1" (click)="selectImageContainer()">
        <ng-container class="upload-container" *ngIf="!checkForExistingImage()">
          <i class="upload-icon" nz-icon [nzType]="'plus'"></i>
          <div class="ant-upload-text">Upload</div>
        </ng-container>
        <div *ngIf="imageContainerSelected==true; then imageContainerIsSelected else imageContainerIsNotSelected">
        </div>
        <ng-template #imageContainerIsSelected>
          <img class="company-image" *ngIf="getImageUrlFromImageContainer()" [src]="getImageUrlFromImageContainer()" tabindex="-1" />
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #imageContainerIsNotSelected>
          <img class="company-image" *ngIf="getImageUrlFromInputBar()" [src]="getImageUrlFromInputBar()" tabindex="-1" />
        </ng-template>
      </nz-upload>
    </div>
    <input class="image-url-input" [nzDisabled]="true" nz-input formControlName="imageUrl" placeholder="Image URL" tabindex="-1" (click)="$event.target.select()" (ngModelChange)="selectImageInputBar()" />
  </nz-form-control>
</nz-form-item>
```

Comment: 1: - how? what code does this 2: how is the url handled in code? 3: how? ... at a guess, your code is wrong, you probably need to fix it with correct code.

Comment: Yep, I've added the relevent code in

Comment: When you are getting the image from imput bar first check if image already exists if yes then empty it and then assign the new url. I didn't see this Condition in your code

Comment: Inside selectImageInputBar() make the this.imageUrl empty

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. Thank you so much for that. I can't believe I overlooked that detail :).

Comment: mark helpful if that worked!!